# How to solve "dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable"?

Tags: dpkg

I have installed the LAMP Server using the command `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`. Thereafter, whenever I open the terminal the following error started to appear:

```
 bash: /home/gaja/.bashrccu: No such file or directory 
 bash: /home/gaja/.bashrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token (' 
 bash: /home/gaja/.bashrc: line 4: see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)'
```

I could get rid of this problem [using the answer given here](https://askubuntu.com/a/400323/114818).

However, now the problem is that I cannot install any thing using the `sudo apt-get` command.

I am trying to become `root` and then re-run the `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` command which gives the following error output:

```
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Following is the complete output of running the commands:

```
gaja@gaja-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for gaja:

root@gaja-System-Product-Name:/home/gaja# sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libdbi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl-modules' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libclass-isa-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-readline' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libdbd-mysql-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-mpm-prefork' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaio1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libmysqlclient18' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libterm-readkey-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libswitch-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
libaio1 is already the newest version.
libapr1 is already the newest version.
libaprutil1 is already the newest version.
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version.
libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version.
libclass-isa-perl is already the newest version.
libdbd-mysql-perl is already the newest version.
libdbi-perl is already the newest version.
libhtml-template-perl is already the newest version.
libswitch-perl is already the newest version.
libterm-readkey-perl is already the newest version.
libwrap0 is already the newest version.
perl is already the newest version.
perl-modules is already the newest version.
ssl-cert is already the newest version.
tcpd is already the newest version.
apache2 is already the newest version.
apache2-bin is already the newest version.
apache2-data is already the newest version.
apache2-mpm-prefork is already the newest version.
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
libmysqlclient18 is already the newest version.
mysql-client-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-client-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-common is already the newest version.
mysql-server is already the newest version.
mysql-server-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-server-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
php5-cli is already the newest version.
php5-common is already the newest version.
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
php5-readline is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

root@gaja-System-Product-Name:/home/gaja# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
root@gaja-System-Product-Name:/home/gaja#
```

Some of the troubleshooting steps that I have taken on suggestion of other members:

```
$ ls -l /bin/tar
ls: cannot access /bin/tar: No such file or directory

$ apt-cache policy tar
tar: Installed: 1.26+dfsg-8 Candidate: 1.26+dfsg-8 Version table: *** 1.26+dfsg-8 0 500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy/main i386 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I have also tried running the following command after switching to `root`, but that doesn't help either:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: We have consolidated all the information which was scattered around for the problem that you are facing. From now onwards, please comment below the answers to which you are replying... If it involves code then it would be better if you [edit] your question and format it properly.. See [editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for more information.. AND PLEASE DO NOT OPEN ANOTHER QUESTION ON THE SAME TOPIC, AS I SAID EARLIER [EDIT] THIS QUESTION...

Comment: Edit the question and include `sudo -i sh -c 'echo $PATH'` output.

Answer (score 1):

The root's `$PATH` environment variable is not set properly, so `dpkg` cannot find `tar` to extract the packages.

Try the following after switchung to root:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

And then run the `apt-get` command again.

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same problem exist

Answer (score 1):

From your question and the following comments it is clear that `tar` is installed but the executable `/bin/tar` is missing. You need to add it manually as your `dpkg` will not work without `tar`.

First check the following files are already there,

```
ls -l /etc/rmt
ls -l /usr/lib/mime/packages/tar
ls -l /usr/sbin/rmt-tar
ls -l /usr/sbin/tarcat
```

I am not listing doc and man files. A complete list can be found [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/tar/filelist)

You can download the `.deb` package for `tar` manually from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/tar). Download the exact package for your architecture.

Next extract the `.deb` file in a system where archive manager is available. If you extract the `.deb` file there will be a directory named `bin` under the main directory. you need to Copy the executable `tar` from extracted `bin` directory to `/bin/`.

You can first put the executable `tar` to your home directory. Next use the following in terminal to copy it to `/bin`,

```
sudo cp tar /bin/
sudo chmod 755 /bin/tar
```

just check the owner of `/bin/tar` is root. and it must have execution permission for all. The output of `ls -l /bin/tar` should look like,

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ...
```

This should work. you may need to install the [suggested packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/tar) if not installed already.

Comment: Sorry, I Couldn't extract the deb file into tar file.

Comment: try to extract the deb file on another computer. then bring the expanded folder to your computer using a flash drive or sftp.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error while trying to do a distribution upgrade from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy (I know this is a Ubuntu Stack Exchange, but my solution may work for you). Here is the command I executed when I received the error:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Here is part of the error:

```
dpkg: 3 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
```

I changed to the root user with the following command and tried again:

```
su root
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And the installation succeeded without error.