# bash: /home/gaja/.bashrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, bashrc

When I open the Terminal I got the following the errors.

```
bash: /home/gaja/.bashrccu: No such file or directory 
bash: /home/gaja/.bashrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token ('
bash: /home/gaja/.bashrc: line 4: see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)'
```

Comment: can you add the output of `head -n 5 ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: how to add the output please send information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get rid of the error messages** use the following command in your terminal,

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

It will replace your corrupt `~/.bashrc` with a fresh one. But any changes in `~/.bashrc` made by you (if any) will be lost.

Do not forget to source the `~/.bashrc`, write in terminal,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**To continue with your existing** `~/.bashrc` you need to add the output of

```
head -n 5 ~/.bashrc
```

So that we can point out the syntax error in your existing `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks sourav, it works fine. but i found a new problem. I couldn't install anything. When i use install command, the following error appears.
“ dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)”

Comment: installation problem with dpkg is another issue. you should first search the solution and if you do not found a solution ask a new question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)